# How do I add a reference to the source code of an assembly reference?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I have a project that has a reference to an assembly (.dll). I have the source code of that assembly, so I would like to see the code while navigating the code, instead of getting the object explorer window. How can I achieve this? (I am thinking about something like include path, but I cant find it)

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What you really need is the pdb file that contains the debugging symbols - generated at the same time as the dll. Stick this next to the dll and it should start working (or if not, you can load it manually).

A source file isn't all that useful unless you are compiling.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the PDB file and the source code, you'll get to the source when the debugger enters the code. However, I don't know of a way of having VS2008 display the sources for a linked DLL in any other scenario.